# Cómo hacer una llamada al sistema que cree un proceso?

Tags: c, linux, schedule, opensuse

Tengo un proyecto de una asignatura de Sistemas Operativos y una de sus partes es hacer una llamada al sistema(en lenguaje C) que **cree un proceso** y lo encole en una de las 99 colas de RT de Linux.

La segunda parte bien, pero no sé muy bien cómo crear un proceso desde el espacio del kernel. Desde el espacio de usuario sería sencillo, usando la llamada `fork()`. ¿Hay forma de hacer algo similar en el kernel?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas utilizar la biblioteca kthread.h del kernel de linux. Te dejo un ejemplo de como crearlo:

```
#include <linux/kthread.h>
...
int funcion_kthread (void * arg);  //Funcion que ejecutará el hilo o proceso
...
struct task_struct *thread1; //Estructura para almacenar informacion de un kthread

thread1 = kthread_create (funcion_kthread, NULL, "thread1");

//Tambien puedes crearlo de la siguiente forma y se ejecutará justo al crearse 

thread1 = kthread_run (funcion_kthread, NULL, "thread1");
```

Puedes ver que kthread_run llama a kthread_create y wake_up_procces [aqui](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re67.html)

Comment: Gracias @eferion